# Create union from multiple column query result

Tags: sql, union

I'm trying to convert the result of an sql query into a set.

The table looks like:

```
create table edges (
  a int,
  b int
);
```

I'd like to use the result of a query as a subquery which needs both columns 'a', and 'b' in a union.

```
select * from ... where id in (select a from edges union select b from edges))
```

The above query works, but it would be great if I could convert the result of the subquery into a union already without needing to join it with another subquery which returns the 2nd column.

```
... in (select makeunion(a, b) from edges)
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

I think if you need to use IN statement you can't avoid UNION. But you can use other WHERE conditions, for example:

```
where EXISTS(select a from edges where a=id or b=id)
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually think you can't factorize this code. UNION requires you to use both queries, one first, one after.

But, you can make a php function that does it for you like :

```
function makeUnion ($table, $rows) {
    $ret = '(';
    $array_rows = explode (',', $rows);
    foreach ($array_rows as $v) {
        if ($ret != '(')
            $ret .= ' UNION ';
        $ret .= 'SELECT ' .$v. ' FROM ' .$table;
    }
$ret .= ')';
return $ret;
}
```

And then use it in your query like this :

```
$sql->query("... IN " .makeUnion('edges','a,b'));
```

I haven't tested it, so don't there may be some errors, but I think you get the point.

Comment: That's not quite what I'm looking for, but thanks anyway. My concern is more related to a performance hit due to the sort of redundant call of the 2nd subquery, and not the fact that it needs to be typed.